# What are various block heights in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've managed a rough method of rating both horse speed and jump distance, but I still need to rate their jump height and I guess an obstacle course with obstacles of varied height could be helpful.

Can someone provide me with list of Minecraft blocks with non-standard heights, including these heights? I know there are blocks both taller than 1m (fence, wall), slightly shorter (soul sand, farmland), half-size (various slabs) and quite thin (pressure plate, carpet, trapdoor) but is there any listing/comparison of these?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Solid block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Solid_block) article has a section with [block heights](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Solid_block#Heights):

> Here is a list of blocks with non-standard heights, from tallest to shortest:

- Fence, Cobblestone Wall: 1 1/2 (also thinner)
- Soul Sand, Chest, Brewing Stand (stand part): 7/8
- End Portal Frame (without Eye of Ender): 13/16
- Enchantment Table, Cocoa Bean (plant), Head (on wall): 3/4
- Bed: 9/16
- Slab, Head (on ground), bottom part of stair: 1/2
- Cake: 7/16
- Daylight Sensor, Flower Pot: 3/8
- Inside of cauldron: 5/16
- Brewing Stand (base), Redstone Repeater, Trapdoor: 1/8
- Snow: 1/8 per layer after the first (0 for one layer, 7/8 for eight)
- Lily Pad: 1/64

Comment: Looks like snow is the ideal material for building height-graduated obstacles.

Comment: Snow looks interesting for this, but I have no idea what this 1/8 per layer means.  Wiki says nothing on it either.

Comment: That snow suggestion was excellent. I made a series of obstacles between 2 and 4 blocks tall gradated by 1/8 block. My fastest horse (speed: 13 hopper pulses per chunk of travel) can barely jump 17 snow slab heights (2 1/8 block), while one quite in the middle of the ranking (16 hopper pulses) can jump almost 4 blocks high (31 slabs, 3 7/8 block height). Additionally, "jump meter" in the orange means 100% jump height, no matter how far in the orange (and then the jump height is the consistent maximum of given horse); anything less and the height is *much* lower.

Comment: After finding some meadows where literally hundreds of horses grazed, I found horses that can jump over five blocks high - something like 5+3/8 even.

Comment: As for snow layers: you can put "snow slab" on top of another "snow slab". The first one (put on the ground) has height 0. Any consecutive layer has 1/8 block height, stacking on top of the previous one, so 2 layers are 1/8 block, 3 layers are 2/8, 4 layers are 3/8 etc. 9 layers is a full block height.